# possible issues in indexing of large documents in solr/lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, buffer, batch-processing

I am trying to index a large data in solr/lucene. Since It is a legacy system and because of some other reasons, I have to do it via a C++ layer. But before doing that I wanted to optimize the process so I did google for that. I found out following things for that:

1. Indexing in batches: which will help me in scenario where indexing will fail in between because of some failure. So i can start with remaining batches again.
2. buffer lookup
3. indexer concurrency

I found the last 2 terms somewhere while looking for different issues, but I am unable to understand it fully.

So if anyone can help me in understanding these two issues and any other issue which may arise.

Comment: How large documents are we talking about? How many documents? Have you tried to actually index some documents to see if you have any issues? Premature optimiziation etc..

Comment: I have not actually indexed the documents. It might happen that i dont need any of the optimizing technique given here. But it is out of my curiosity that i want to understand these two terms(buffer lookup and indexer concurrency) in context of batch-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean when you're mentioning "**Buffer Lookup**" - usually this is the case of allowing a server to have a decent in-memory cache, where as many queries as possible can be answered without having to recalculate the intersection between documents and which documents are contained in a certain set for each query. For Solr this is configured using the different [*cache](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching)-settings. The requirements will be different for most applications, depending on query load, field definitions, etc. Performing a commit (making documents visible in the index) usually expires caches, as the cache might no longer be valid.

**Indexer Concurrency** allows a server to insert documents into the actual index from many threads at the same time, without locking between the threads. Lucene made [concurrent indexing possible back in 2011](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/05/03/lucene-indexing-gains-concurrency/) (for Lucene 4.0), and allows faster and more efficient updates of the index. Whether this matters depends on your application.